# Configuring Jest in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm trying to use Jest to aid Puppeteer testing in WebStorm.

It is my first time using Jest and it looks just the framework I need to help with testing, assertions, setup and teardown etc...

Trouble is, WebStorm won't recognise the keywords e.g. beforeAll, describe, afterAll.  Here's a snippet:

[image]

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
"name": "ui-tests",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "End-to-end UI tests",
"author": "John Doe",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "debug": "NODE_ENV=debug npm test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jest-cli": "^22.0.4",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "puppeteer": "^1.9.0"
}
```

}

I have the following plugins installed:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "WebStorm won't recognize", what do you mean exactly? I have my jest.config.js file setup and configured, and when I run 'npm run test', or even just 'jest', from the builtin terminal it just runs...

Comment: It does doesn't see "beforeAll" as a keyword; it's not highlighted like I see it in VSCode. I guess I need to learn more about the jest config file

Answer (score 11):

I installed "jest" library as it described here:

> In Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries,
>   press Download..., select 'jest' from the list of available stubs,
>   press Download and Install

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000357324-Get-rid-of-Unresolved-function-method-variable-warning-in-Jest-test-files

That helped me with most definitions. Though I still have the same issue with "jest-puppeteer".